# Possible to call glNormal3f for triangle in immediate mode?

Tags: c++, opengl

Following is a surface normal question for a triangle mesh:

```
float3 calcNormal( float3 p0 , float3 p1 , float3 p2 ){
float3 V = { p1.x - p0.x , p1.y - p0.y , p1.z - p0.z };
float3 U = { p2.x - p0.x , p2.y - p0.y , p2.z - p0.z };

float3 normal = {V.y * U.z - U.y*V.z , V.x * U.z - U.x * V.z , V.x * U.y - U.x * V.y };
return normal;
}
```

Triangle normal function ↑

```
glNormal3f(calcNormal( { i*size , heightMap[i][j]*h , j*size } , {(i+1)*size, heightMap[i+1][j]*h,j*size  } , { i*size,heightMap[i][j+1]*h,j*size  } ).x ,
                   calcNormal( { i*size , heightMap[i][j]*h , j*size } , {(i+1)*size, heightMap[i+1][j]*h,j*size  } , { i*size,heightMap[i][j+1]*h,j*size  } ).y,
                   calcNormal( { i*size , heightMap[i][j]*h , j*size } , {(i+1)*size, heightMap[i+1][j]*h,j*size  } , { i*size,heightMap[i][j+1]*h,j*size  } ).z);
```

With code above, I calculate the normal of 1st triangle of 2 triangles in one square, and with the one below, I do calculate the 2nd triangle's normal (I guess).

```
glNormal3f(calcNormal( { (i+1)*size , heightMap[i+1][j]*h , j*size } , {(i)*size, heightMap[i][j+1]*h,(j+1)*size  } , { (i+1)*size,heightMap[i+1][j+1]*h,(j+1)*size  } ).x ,
                   calcNormal( { (i+1)*size , heightMap[i+1][j]*h , j*size } , {(i)*size, heightMap[i][j+1]*h,(j+1)*size  } , { (i+1)*size,heightMap[i+1][j+1]*h,(j+1)*size  } ).y,
                   calcNormal( { (i+1)*size , heightMap[i+1][j]*h , j*size } , {(i)*size, heightMap[i][j+1]*h,(j+1)*size  } , { (i+1)*size,heightMap[i+1][j+1]*h,(j+1)*size  } ).z);
```

Is it possible to use the triangle normals instead of vertex normals in this the case below, if so , how do I place the normal calls?

```
...
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
...       
glNormal3f(/*calculated normal*/); //I know these are supposed to be vertex normals
glColor3f(0,color_map ,color_ugate-color_map );
glVertex3f(i*size , heightMap[i][j]*h , j*size);

glNormal3f(/*calculated normal*/);
glColor3f(0,color_map ,color_ugate-color_map  );
glVertex3f((i+1)*size , heightMap[i+1][j]*h , j*size);

glNormal3f(/*calculated normal*/);
glColor3f(0,color_map ,color_ugate-color_map  );
glVertex3f(i*size , heightMap[i][j+1]*h , (j+1)*size);

glNormal3f(/*calculated normal*/);
glColor3f(0,color_map ,color_ugate-color_map  );
glVertex3f((i+1)*size , heightMap[i+1][j+1]*h , (j+1)*size);
...
glEnd();
...
```

Comment: Why do you not use a function to calculate the normal? Why do you use `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences, which are deprecated since decades? Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

Comment: Am I not using a function here? I'm just asking if I can use a triangle normal -which I do calculate in a function- instead of vertex normals. I'm aware that this isn't the most elegant way but is easy to write. @Rabbid76